# Datepicker maximumDate stuck on yesterday day during early time of the current day

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I have a date picker that is set to not allow users to pick future dates. It's maximum date is set for the current time on viewDidLoad.

```
dateDatePicker.maximumDate = NSDate()
```

But I've been noticing a bug. Today until midday the maximum date was yesterdays date. But now, after midday it is showing todays date.

**The way I implemented it:** The date picker is shown and hidden with alpha when user wants to use it. So I am setting the maximum date not every time the picker is shown but once it loads the view it is in.

So I am not sure if this is a bug? 
Is it has to do with timezones? 
Or has to do with the fact that I am only calling dateDatePicker.maximumDate once when they view loaded and that could have happened days ago? 
Or if I should reset the maximumDate every time I show the datePicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should almost certainly set the maximum date each time you show the date picker.

If you set the maximum date on a previous day and then never updated it nor closed the view controller the it wouldn't change.

Set it in viewWillAppear, not viewDidLoad.

If that doesn't work, use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents to build an NSDate which is 23:59 on the current date (fetch the MM/DD/YYYY from the current date as date components, then manually set the time to 23:59. That should work.